# Streaming inner JSONArray records with Jackson avoiding memory collection

Tags: java, json, jackson, streaming

Been recently trying to dig into how to stream JSON content via an HTTP endpoint as I don't want to store the whole JSON in memory before sending the response.

However, I have some doubts related on how to do this and if my previous JSON schema has to change in order to cope with streaming and later parsing.

Currently what I have (and would like to still have doing streaming) is the following.

```
    {
        "content": [ // I don't want to wait for this array to be populated to flush it.
            {
                "key": "value",
                "yet": "another_value"
            }, // read individual nested record, flush it
            {
                "key": "valueagain",
                "yet": "another_value_in_here"
            } // read individual nested record, flush it
        ],
        "random": {
            "more": "fields",
            "in": {
                 "here": "yeah"
            }
        }
    }
```

My doubt here is, is there a way (using Jackson or any other Java lib) to stream inner parts of a JSON without waiting for closing the value of a given key?

Let's say I want to start streaming

```
{ 
    "content": [
         ...
```

And then all the contents following that...

```
{
        "key": "value",
        "yet": "another_value"
}
```

Or the way of doing this is changing the overall result to this.

```
[
  {
    "key": "value",
    "yet": "another_value"
  },
  {
    "key": "valueagain",
    "yet": "another_value_in_here"
  },
  {
    "more": "fields",
    "in": {
      "here": "yeah"
    }
  }
]
```

So, basically, having a `JsonGenerator`, would I be able to flush incomplete arrays such as in my example?

```
jGenerator.writeStartObject();
jGenerator.writeFieldName("content");    
jGenerator.writeStartArray();
jGenerator.flush(); // initial stream, records incoming within next flush. Can this be streamed?

jGenerator.writeStartObject();    
jGenerator.writeStringField("key", "value");
jGenerator.writeStringField("yet", "another_value");
jGenerator.writeEndObject();
jGenerator.flush(); // streaming individual JSON object

... so on so forth until array is complete ...

jGenerator.writeEndArray();
jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("random");
```

Comment: JSON is text, so streaming and flushing will happen exactly in the same order as you see on the screen. Opening brackets are written before ending brackets. Streaming is not a problem unless you explicitly build the String first before transmitting it, otherwise you can just generate the JSON to an outputstream (or its framework specific equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

If you can get input stream to your Json without putting whole content in memory. For example you can have it saved on HDD and just get `InputStream` from `File`.

With jackson you can have something like this:

```
  private final JsonParser jp;

  public JsonArrayInputStreamWrapper(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    this.jp = new JsonFactory().createParser(inputStream);
    setUpCursorToContentArray();
  }

  private void setUpCursorToContentArray() throws IOException {
    // validate if json contains "content" key
    do {
      if (jp.nextToken() == null)
        throw new JsonException("Provided input doesn't contain content.");
    } while (!"content".equals(jp.getText()));

    // set up coursor on first array that is found after "content"
    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
      if (jp.currentToken() == null)
        // throw exception when there weren't any array
        throw new JsonException("Content input is malformed.");
    }
  }
```

So my idea was to set up my coursor in the place where I'd like to start processing in the constructor of this so called wrapper. This way after successful initialization of object I can use `hasNext()` and `next()` for a change.

```
  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    if(jp.isClosed()) {
      // has to be handled
    }
    return jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT
  }

  @Override
  public Map next() {
    // where mapper is jackson ObjectMapper
    return mapper.readValue(jp, Map.class);
  }
```

This can be used as following:

```
while (wrapper.hasNext()) {
    var inv = wrapper.next();
    //processing
}
```

Do not forget to `jp.close()` after you finish processing.